# Twitter Api 1.1 GET followers/ids count doesn't work

Tags: php, twitter, get

```
$cursor = -1;
$limit = 5;
while($cursor != 0){
    $parameters = array('screen_name' => $q, 'cursor' => $cursor , 'count' => $limit);
    $method = "followers/ids";
    $response2 = $connection->get($method, $parameters);
    $followerlist = array_merge($followerlist,$response2->ids);
    $cursor = $response2->next_cursor;

}
```

I did a limit of 5, but it gave me the all of followers id... if the user has 20 followers it gives me the 20 ids but I need only 5. I gave a count parameter of 5 but it seems to ignore it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see it is in a while loop... is it possible that it's getting 5 at a time until it gets all 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need only 5 results a time,there is no need of a while loop.Just specify `'count' => 5`